# No tag for Da Vinci's Demons

Tags: discussion

I like the series called "Da Vinci's Demons" written by David S. Goyer. I found no tag related to this series. It is good to having tag for that . There are so many questions related to series and I understand you will have also. (I don't have privilege otherwise I will not ask this question :P).

Comment: Tags are only present when there is a question about it, even if a new user ask a question and can't find his movie/TV series tag Moderators and high rep user are always there to help.

Comment: ok @AnkitSharma . thank you for your information.  I have one question related to this series so I will ask it later .

Comment: If a tag only exists for one question, it gets auto deleted after some time. So unless there is two da Vinci questions it won't last.

Comment: @cde This rule was [explicitly disabled](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/897/49) on this site a long time ago. There are various tags that only have one single question.

Comment: I have to first add question for that right @NapoleonWilson

Comment: @KDeogharkar Yes, a tag has to have a question. Tags without a question will get auto-deleted in the same way as you can't create a tag without asking a question, as explained in the question this is a duplicate to. But this site does *not* apply the general SE rule of auto-deleting tags with only one question that cde mentions in his comment.

Comment: ok understood thanks @NapoleonWilson